# Capturing Errors and Warnings From LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have trying to upload file using LOAD INFILE command,
Some point of file data is skipping, Please any one tell me how to find out the skipped lines or error handling in this case.

Comment: Hi.. In linux I have tried with above solution,without local I have tried, but it is not finding file itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get "Skipped records" using "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" copy the data file to the actual database server and do the load without the "LOCAL" keyword. 
This will then stop when an error occurs, 9 times out of 10 it will be index issues and you will know why there are skipped records.

e.g. LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myinfile.txt';
Query OK, 288168 rows affected (1 min 44.49 sec)
Records: 494522 Deleted: 0 Skipped: 206354 Warnings: 0

LOAD DATA INFILE '/data/input/myinfile.txt';
Query OK, 252243 rows affected (0.02 sec)
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '5935009001-2008-08-03 04:19:18' for key 1

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: Hi.. In linux  I have tried with above solution,without local I have tried, but it is not finding file itself...